# PHP - preg_match with for loop $i

Tags: php, preg-match

I am new to Php and want to do a `preg_match` to grab out data from a local HTML file. The code I wrote as below:

```
preg_match('#\<span class=\"creativeT\" id=\"SCreativeDesc1\">(.*?)\<\/span>#',$html,$creativedesc);
```

it works fine when specific SCreativeDesc"1", but when I put it in a Loop with $i (i.e. SCreativeDesc$i), it fire me an error.

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$totalCreatives;$i++){
    preg_match('#\<span class=\"creativeT\" id=\"SCreativeDesc$i\">(.*?)\<\/span>#',$html,$creativedesc);
}
```

either I put:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$totalCreatives;$i++){
    preg_match('#\<span class=\"creativeT\" id=\"SCreativeDesc" . $i . "\">(.*?)\<\/span>#',$html,$creativedesc);
}
```

It's also not work, may I how to do that with a loop? As in the HTML it repeats around 100 times, I don't want to write it up to 100 lines for this grabbing.

Comment: You can't just put a variable inside a regex pattern.

Comment: um, yes you can, php will interpret it as a string and make the replacement for the variable's value if you use double quotes rather than single quotes and then the regex just sees the literal value.

Comment: you can check for a number using: `\d{1,3}`

Comment: @Jack you can treat a regex pattern in php as if it were a normal string (because it is).  So yes you can interpolate and concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop here.

```
preg_match('#\<span class=\"creativeT\" id=\"SCreativeDesc[0-9]+\">(.*?)\<\/span>#',$html,$creativedesc);
```

You could also limit the number range with slightly more complex regex, but I have a feeling this is sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$totalCreatives;$i++){
  $re = "#\<span class=\"creativeT\" id=\"SCreativeDesc" . $i . "\">(.*?)\<\/span>#";
  preg_match($re,$html,$creativedesc);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't even close the quotes correctly.  You're using a single quote `'` at the beginning and closing with a double quote `"`.
What you want is:

```
preg_match('#\<span class=\"creativeT\" id=\"SCreativeDesc' . $i . '\">(.*?)\<\/span>#',$html,$creativedesc);
```